# Can we write code inside CollectionDefinition class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, automation, xunit

```
public class MyFirstFixture : IDisposable
{
    public MySecondFixture()
    {
        // Some initialization
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Some cleanup
    }
}

[CollectionDefinition("MyCollection")]
public class MyCollectionDefinition : ICollectionFixture<MyFirstFixture>
{
    //Can I add code in this section?
}

[Collection("MyCollection")]
public class TestClass1
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Do some testing
    }
}
```

Here I have defined MyFirstFixture and created a collection definition with CollectionFixture and that collection name is being used in tests. 
Can I write the code in the CollectionDefinition section as well? Will that get executed whenever the collection is mentioned in a test?

Comment: Did you try to write code in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at the documentation:
https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context

There is an example:

```
[CollectionDefinition("Database collection")]
public class DatabaseCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
}
```